# No exception in JAVA program when it reads xlsx file with XSSFWorkbook class in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, unhandled-exception, xssf

I'm developing an eclipse based Java application. But I can't catch the exception. I want to read an excel file(.xlsx) using `HSSF` and `XSSF` simultaneously. But `HSSF` works properly otherwise XSSF doesn't.  Here is my code. After `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);` statement the program count goes to finally statement.
Thanks in advance.

```
 try {
        if (FileFormat == FILE_FORMAT_XLS) {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(szFileName));
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        }
        // This block does not work properly.
        else if (FileFormat == FILE_FORMAT_XLSX) {
            file = new File(szFileName);
            if (file.exists() == false || file.isFile() == false || file.canRead() == false) {
                throw new IOException(szFileName);
            }

            pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg); // **<- Here is the problem.**
        }

        if (wb != null) {
            evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            sheetNum = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
            for (int i = 0; i < sheetNum; i++) {
                for (Row row : wb.getSheetAt(i)) {
                    person ps = new person();
                    if (getPerson(row, ps) == true) {
                        list.add((Object) ps);
                        log.addLog(list.size() + " " + ps.getName() + ", " + ps.getHanName() + ", " + ps.getEnName() + ", " + ps.getBirthDay() + ", " + ps.getCellPhone() + ", " + ps.getID() + ", " + ps.getAddress());
                    } else {
                        log.addLog("total count = " + list.size());
                        ps = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.addLog("can not open workbook");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        if (wb != null) {
            wb = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have all the [Apache POI component jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on your classpath? And are you using the latest version?

Comment: What's the exception? Provide the stacktrace.

Comment: I use POI-xxx-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar. I think I have completely done for dependencies on my classpath because HSSF was doing well.

Comment: There is no exception. That's my question. :D

Answer (score 0):

Does the program go to `finally` without catching the exception?
Either the wb object is null or there will be an exception stack trace.

Also the wb object has to be of appropriate type. Either HSSF or XSSF.
Try instantiating the xssfworkbook like

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(szFileName);